# Xcode 8.2.1 Performance issue with Macbook pro

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I have a MacBook pro(mid-2012)with following configuration(8GB RAM,  MacOS Sierra, and 512 GB HDD). I updated my Xcode version from 8.2 to 8.2.1. After updating to that version system not responding properly (till 8.2 it works properly), I have to wait 5 or more minutes for one click. So please help me on that to fix that issue. For that performance issue,

**Note:**  I reinstall MacOS twice but getting the same performance issue again and again when I open Xcode before that it works properly.

**Steps to Reproduce:**
Open Xcode with any existing project and open simulator from Xcode developer tools then you will see that system is not responding properly.

**Expected Results:**

If it will work till 8.2 then it will also work in Xcode 8.2.1 in MacBook pro

Following is my system configuration and activity monitor results.

[image] CPU Usage

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StFSa.png)

[image]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StFSa.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lEj3.png system configurtion
  [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sgnO.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdoZW.png before xcode start
[image]
    after xcode and simulator both starts cpu usage in activity monitor

[image]CPU usage when both are running.

Answer (score 0):

Check your "`Activity Monitor`" Mac App, monitor which tasks are taking more memory (***%CPU***). Try to force quit unused apps / tasks. And try again.

```
Finder -> Applications -> Activity Monitor
```

[image]

Comment: i am currently running google chrome, xcode and simulator. and in activity monitor when opens xcode and simulator it comsumes 7.58gb RAM

Comment: See attached screen shot(above), Check which tasks are taking more %CPU and try to quit those tasks and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I have a macbook pro(middle-2012) in my home, and I can not use it to write the code any more, because it is too slow, I promise, if you replace a newer macbook pro, I think the issue will not comes.

In my company, I use the company's Macbook pro(2015) or Mac Mini(2014 late), with `Xcode 8.2.1`.

[image]

[image]

These there will not get slow, improve the configuration of your hardware.